# "None" keeps popping up in my output of a calculator program

Tags: python

Problem showcase
[image]

I've just started to code in python and coded a calculator (its unfinished atm) it works fine except for the fact that "none" keeps popping up in the output. Here is my code.

```
num1 = float(input(print("Enter the first value ")))
num2 = float(input(print("Enter the second value ")))
operator = input("Enter the operator you want to calculate with;+,-,* ")
sum = num1+num2
product = num1*num2
difference = num1-num2
if operator == "+":
    print(sum)
elif operator=="*":
    print(product)
else:
    print(difference)
```

Output:

```
None 1
Enter the second value
None 2
Enter the operator you want to calculate with;+,-,*
3.0
```

Any fixes available for this? I've seen another query with the same issue but different code so I didn't understand that a bit.

Comment: you shouldn't include print in the input

Comment: I didn't those are just markers for the problem

Comment: Please show actual code that replicates your issue

Comment: This is the actual code

Comment: don't use `sum` it is a keyword  use `summation` instead don't
`float(input(print("Enter the first value ")))`  is wrong  use `input("Enter the first value")` instead

Comment: You are getting `None` because you have `print()` inside the `input()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You code should look like this:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter the first value ")) 
num2 = float(input("Enter the second value "))
operator = input("Enter the operator you want to calculate with;+,-,* ")
summ = num1+num2
product = num1*num2
difference = num1-num2
if operator == "+":
    print(summ)
elif operator=="*":
    print(product)
else:
    print(difference)
```

Without the two `print()` in the `input()`.

And so the output is:

```
Enter the second value 2
Enter the second value 2
Enter the operator you want to calculate with;+,-,* *
4.0
```

Comment: It is like that I just added those to identify the problem, ill just edit it

Comment: I get the "none" tho

Comment: also correct the `sum` to something else like `summ`

Answer (score 0):

`sum` is an inbuilt function in python, (don't quote me on it) but I believe your variable will replace the inbuilt type but either way it's terrible style and should be avoided. Also you just put the string you want to display within input so the code should be.

`input("input message")`
not `input(print("input message"))`

I also do not understand why you are calculating the sum, product and difference before asking for the input as this just adds unnecessary calculation. Your code would be far superior as:

```py
if operator == "+":
    print(num_1 + num_2)
elif operator == "-":
    print(num_1 - num_2)
elif operator == "*":
    print(num_1 * num_2)
```

As for the None type all functions in python have a return type (if no return type is specified then the return type is "None") I believe this is why you are getting None for your input values.